# composer - Invalid working directory specified error

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to install the Drupal Console (https://drupalconsole.com/)

As per the instructions here:
https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/getting/windows.html

I have Git for windows, composer, PHP, and sqlite-tools-win32-x86 all 
installed.

I have defined everything as per the instructions on that page.

When I run:
$ composer global require drupal/console:@stable

I'm getting:

```
admin@Dxxx MINGW64 ~
$ composer global require drupal/console:@stable
Changed current directory to C:/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

That lead me to look into the  composer settings. When i run

$ composer -d

I get:

```
[RuntimeException]
  Invalid working directory specified,  does not exist.
```

Looks like something is wrong with my composer installation. Any idea what?

Comment: Did you move composer to work globally?

Comment: If by globally you mean that the composer command works from any directory than yes.

Comment: composer -d requires a working directory path to be provided. To confirm if composer you can check via following commands. 

composer -V 
composer list
composer diagnose

That being said, your problem doesn't seem to lay with composer.

Comment: "working directory path" - what does that mean exactly?? also, the diagnose command yields OK for all checks.

Comment: working directory path is specified to indicate where composer should be rooted to work and is irrelevant to your issue since you made it to work globally. Did you check if repo path is correct? Composer messages say 'Nothing to install or update'